# how to get model attribute value in angularjs from spring controller

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest

I have spring controller defined as

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello")
    public String home(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, Model model) {        

            model.addAttribute("Authorization", "test string");

            return "/index";
    }  
}
```

Is there any way I could get attribute "Authorization" in angularjs controller?

Comment: What does the /index view do with this attribute? Typically, angular controllers get their data from JSON HTTP responses.

Comment: @JBNizet index.html is a html file binding with angularjs controller. "Authorization" attribute needs to be used in angularjs controller to make another post call.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`($location.search()).Authorization`

More details about `$location` and parameters: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: I am not able to use model attribute in angularjs using this

Comment: More examples please, I want to convert my spring controller to angular

Answer (score 1):

try ng-init="var = ${Authorization}"
then in controller $scope.var

Answer (score 0):

I've faced with the same issue, but `($location.search()).attributeKey` doesn't work for me. In my angularJs controller I'm receiving 'undefined' value via `($location.search()).attributeKey`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for some time . I used a 'hackish' way to access  a variable added as a modal attribute in the backend .

let say you have added `"some-data"` to the model like follows.

```
model.addAttribute("some-data-id", "some-data");
```

in the jsp where the ctrl is initializing add the attribute to a hidden html element such as a span

```
<span style="display:none" id="someDataId">${some-data-id}</span>
```

and in the controller , retrieve the value using `angular.element('#some-data-id').innerHTML`