# how to access model value in angular controller

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I want to access model attribute values in angular controller. I have returned from spring controller like this.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/helloWorld", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void helloWorld(HttpRequest req, Model model) {
         String typeOfMoney = req.getSession().getAttribute("typeOfMoney").toString();
        model.addAttribute("typeOfMoney",typeOfMoney);
    return "MyJsp";
    }
```

That `typeOfMoney` need to assign in my angular controller. How can I get this `typeOfMoney` in angular controller.like the below

```
 var app = angular.module('App', ['ui.bootstrap']);

    app.controller('fcController', function($scope) {
        var y = typeOfMoney;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Model and view(i.e attributes of request or response or Session) is specific to Spring(i.e Java) It can't be accessed in Angular Js directly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929602/how-to-get-model-attribute-value-in-angularjs-from-spring-controller

Comment: In this link they said it is posible, But not working to me

Comment: $location will give url params not attributes of response or request of JSP

Comment: There is one trick i have used is set Attribute value in hidden field and then you can access it from angular controller.